# Split environment wrong braces dimensions

Tags: equations, line-breaking, braces

I have to split a quite long formula. I used a nested split environment but I have to break curly braces from one line to another using `\right.` and `\left.`
The curly braces I get have different dimensions. I tried using \Biggl and \Biggr but they are too small. Here is my source:

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:splitted}
\begin{split}
  c(x, y, t) &= \frac{M/Y}{b\sqrt{4\pi\left(\D_x^T+\K_x\right)t}}
  \exp\left[-\frac{\left(x-Ut-x_0\right)^2}{4\left(\D_x^T+\K_x\right)t}\right]\\
  &\begin{split}\frac{b}{\sqrt{4\pi\left(\D_y^T+\K_y\right)t}}
  \left\{
\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}%
\exp\left[-\frac{\left(y-y_0+2jb\right)^2}{4\left(\D_y^T+\K_y\right)}\right]\right.&%
  \\ + \left.%
    \exp\left[-\frac{\left(y+y_0+2jb\right)^2}{4\left(\D_y^T+\K_y\right)}\right]\right\}&
  \end{split}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a `+` or `\times` missing before the second line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need of `\phantom` and `split`; the best approach in this case is with the `multlined` environment provided by `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\D}{\mathbf{D}}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbf{K}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:split}
\begin{gathered}
  c(x, y, t) =
\begin{multlined}[t]
  \frac{M/Y}{b\sqrt{4\pi(\D_x^T+\K_x)t}}
  \exp\biggl[-\frac{(x-Ut-x_0)^2}{4(\D_x^T+\K_x)t}\biggr]\\
  \frac{b}{\sqrt{4\pi(\D_y^T+\K_y)t}}
  \biggl\{
    \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\biggl[-\frac{(y-y_0+2jb)^2}{4(\D_y^T+\K_y}\biggr]\\
    {}+\exp\biggl[-\frac{(y+y_0+2jb)^2}{4(\D_y^T+\K_y)}\biggr]
  \biggr\}
\end{multlined}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Notice that I've removed *all* `\left` and `\right` before the inner parentheses: they aren't needed and add spacing.

By choosing `\biggl[` and `\biggr]` instead of `\left[` and `\right]` we get uniform height of the brackets and we can use also the same size for the braces. In general, when a summation has limits above and below, `\biggl` and `\biggr` are to be preferred to `\left` and `\right` that produce too large symbols.

The wrapping `gathered` environment is used for getting the equation number centered with respect to the whole formula.

[image]

---

A refinement can be obtained by seeing that the two square root symbols are different though they contain similar formulas. If the second one is typed as

```
\sqrt{\smash[b]{4\pi(\D_y^T+\K_y)t}\vphantom{_x}}
```

the result will be

[image]

Comment: Oh, race condition! I answered also about `\bigg` and such. I removed my answer since yours is more complete.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Without `gathered` the equation number is aligned to the first row. One might dispense with it using simply `multline`, but losing the automatic alignment of the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not a good idea to nest the `split` environment, and it does not seem necessary in your code. To fix the brace size you can insert an invisible sum in the last line via `\vphantom` that forces the closing brace to be higher:

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:splitted}
\begin{split}
  c(x, y, t) &= \frac{M/Y}{b\sqrt{4\pi\left(\D_x^T+\K_x\right)t}}
  \exp\left[-\frac{\left(x-Ut-x_0\right)^2}{4\left(\D_x^T+\K_x\right)t}\right] \\
  & \phantom{{}={}} \frac{b}{\sqrt{4\pi\left(\D_y^T+\K_y\right)t}}
  \left\{ \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}  \exp\left[-\frac{\left(y-y_0+2jb\right)^2}{4\left(\D_y^T+\K_y\right)}\right]\right.  \\ 
  & \phantom{{}={}} + \left. \vphantom{\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}} \exp\left[-\frac{\left(y+y_0+2jb\right)^2}{4\left(\D_y^T+\K_y\right)}\right]\right\}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I also added invisible `=` after the alignment characters in the second and third line, so everything is right to the `=`.

To get the last line flushed right, you can nest a `multlined` from package `mathtools` in it:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
...
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:splitted2}
\begin{split}
  c(x, y, t) &= \frac{M/Y}{b\sqrt{4\pi\left(\D_x^T+\K_x\right)t}}
  \exp\left[-\frac{\left(x-Ut-x_0\right)^2}{4\left(\D_x^T+\K_x\right)t}\right] \\
  & \phantom{{}={}}
  \begin{multlined}
  \frac{b}{\sqrt{4\pi\left(\D_y^T+\K_y\right)t}}
  \left\{ \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}  \exp\left[-\frac{\left(y-y_0+2jb\right)^2}{4\left(\D_y^T+\K_y\right)}\right]\right.  \\ 
   + \left. \vphantom{\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}} \exp\left[-\frac{\left(y+y_0+2jb\right)^2}{4\left(\D_y^T+\K_y\right)}\right]\right\}
  \end{multlined}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: I did not want last line to be aligned with =, that's why I used a nested split. Anyway a phantom sum works, thank you.